# Is this correct way to prove two spans are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I need to prove the span=$\left( \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$ and the span=$\left( \begin{bmatrix} -1\\3\\7\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 8\\-9\\4\end{bmatrix}\right)$ are equal. My solution is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-3&x\\-1&4&y\\6&1&z\end{bmatrix} \implies \text{rref}(A)= A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-3&x\\0&1&(2y+x)/5\\0&0&z-5x-4y\end{bmatrix}
$$
rref is not complete though. The plane equation is $z-5x-4y=0$. For the second span, I get
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&8&x\\3&-9&y\\7&4&z\end{bmatrix} \implies \text{rref}(A)= A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&8&x\\0&1&(y+3x)/15\\0&0&z-5x-4y\end{bmatrix}
$$
Again rref is not complete. The plane equation for the second span is $z-5x-4y=0$. Because both spans describe same plane, they are equal. Is this valid proof?

Comment: Yes, you proved correctly that both spans are equal to the plane $z=5x+4y$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you!

Comment: Another way, which is maybe the intention in this case because the numbers are nice, is to try to write the generators of one span in terms of the generators of the other, then vice versa.

Comment: @prets what are generators?

Comment: The vectors in your big set of parentheses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of alternative, as hinted at in a comment.

By definition, the span of a collection of vectors is the set of all linear combinations of those vectors. In other words, the span
$$ U = \left( \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\1\end{bmatrix}\right) $$
is the set of all vectors
$$ a \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\1\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}\label{eq:span1} $$
for scalars $a$ and $b$.
Now if we can show that the vectors generating the span
$$ W = \left( \begin{bmatrix} -1\\3\\7\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 8\\-9\\4\end{bmatrix}\right) $$
can be written as $\eqref{eq:span1}$ for some $a$ and $b$, then it must be the case that $W \subseteq U$, since $U$ contains *at least* the generators of $W$.

Well the numbers in this case are fairly nice, so this isn't so hard! Notice how
$$
 (1)\begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix} +(1) \begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 3 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
 (1)\begin{bmatrix} 2\\-1\\6\end{bmatrix} +(-2) \begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}8 \\ -9 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}.
$$

To show that $U = W$, we can now either (a) do the same thing in reverse, showing that the generators of $U$ can be written as linear combinations of the generators of $W$, or if that sounds boring we can (b) use a dimension argument: Both $\dim U = \dim W = 2$ (why?) and $W \subseteq U$, so $U = W$.

(In the particular case of these nice spans of two vectors, we could rephrase all of this as saying: both $U$ and $W$ are planes, and the calculations above show that these planes intersect in *more* than a line, which forces them to be exactly the same planes!)

Answer (score 0):

Based on our [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71083880/2476977), it seems that you're really trying to implement this check with Matlab. With that said, here are two approaches that you could consider. I'll define
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&-3\\-1&4\\6&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{-1&8\\3&-9\\7&4}.
$$
**Approach 1:**

```
N=null(A); 
if norm(N'*B,'fro') < 1e-10:
    disp('Span of cols of B contained in span of cols of A')
if rank(A) == rank(B)
    disp('Ranks are the same!')
end
```

$N$ in the above is a matrix such that $N^Tx = 0$ (i.e. `N'*x = 0`) is an equation for the space containing the columns of $A$. The columns of $B$ lie within the span of the columns of $A$ if and only if `N'*B` is the zero matrix (up to numerical precision). In order to ensure the reverse containment, it suffices to check that the dimensions of these spans are the same.

**Approach 2:**

```
if rank(A) = rank([A, B]) & rank(A) == rank(B):
    disp('Spans are the same!')
end
```

$A$ and $[A \mid B]$ have the same rank if and only if the columns of $B$ are contained within the span of the columns of $A$. As before, after this it suffices to check whether $A$ and $B$ have the same rank.

Comment: It is useful answer but I'm not seeking Matlab for this proof. However, in the referenced link, I'm studying the spanning vectors for one span.